# Google Forms question based on previous choice

Tags: google-apps-script

I am collecting data from my students. I have their names, classrooms and  attendee's numbers in a Google Spreadsheet.

[image: Table]

I want to have a Google Forms where first they put their classroom (drop-down list). Then, they have to put their number (drop-down list). However, the number of options in this second question is not all the same. Each classroom has different number of students. So, the number of options for the second question is based on the first choice. 
For the third question, I want them to put their name. To avoid them putting different name from what I have, I decided to put a drop-down list where the only available choice is their name (based on the answer of questions 1 and 2). 
Is there a way to access the choices of previous questions before submitting them in order to determine the options for next questions? 
[image: Forms]
For example, when the answer for first question is "A", there will be only four option for second question i.e. numbers 1-4. And, when the answer for this question is 4, then the only option for third question is "Doug".

I have tried using sections. But it will require so much works because there are more than 200 students in 16 classrooms. I tried using pre-filled forms (generating url for each students). This will require so much works too. Is there a way to access current response (not the last one) and use it to determine the next question's options? Thanks for the help.

Comment: As far a I know, you can't interact programmatically with Google  Forms when they are running. I would do it with a WebApp.

Comment: Thanks, I have thought so. But, I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: I’d be glad to help you with that if you like to learn Google Apps Script. In fact I have an example that has an interactive drop-down for countries districts and cities that I can share with you.

Comment: @Cooper, I am learning, actually. But, so far, I haven't found any workaround. If you can help me and give me an example, I will be grateful.